# The order structure of the dual space of $C(X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

A "state" is positive linear functional on a partially ordered vector space with order unit that sends the order unit to $1$.  This definition can be extended uniquely to complex-valued linear functionals.  What I would like to know is why a state of $C(X)$ has norm $1$.  If a linear functional $
\phi$ is a hermitian state on $C(X)$, then $\phi(\overline{f}g)$ defines an inner product, so by Cauchy-Schwarz it has norm equal to $1$.  But why does this follow for any state?  It does not seem to me that an arbitary state needs to be positive or real-valued or hermition.  Of course an arbitary state decomposes as the sum of hermitian states, but this only shows that it has norm less than or equal to $2$.

Comment: What is an "order unit"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_unit

Comment: Thanks ${}{}{}$

Comment: @Ruy Wow you have no idea how much this has been driving me crazy.  thank you

Comment: Every state is Hermitian!  This is because $\phi(f)$ is positive, hence real, for a positive $f$.  Since any real function $g$ is the difference of positives, then $\phi(g)$ is also real.  Given any other $f$, write $f=g+ih$, with $f,g$ real, so $$\phi(\bar f) = \phi(g-ih) =\phi(g) -i\phi(h) = \overline{\phi(f)}.$$ Therefore $\phi$ is Hermitian.